# Highcharts not taking up full width?

Tags: javascript, json, charts, highcharts

I've setup this simple chart: https://jsfiddle.net/2r6a7og0/
I've removed all paddings and margins + I've set the xAxis and yAxis to not be visible - However, it seems it is still not taking up the full width of the area, meaning I have white space to the left and right of the chart?

The config for the chart:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'area',
    marginLeft:0,
    marginRight:0
  },
    xAxis: {
    visible: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    visible: false
  },
  series: [{
    data: [4, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3]
  }]

});
```

I've also tried adding spacingLeft:0 and spacingRight:0, without any luck

I have no idea where the whitespace is coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling axis visibility is not enough to remove visible paddings. In that case, it is necessary to set `xAxis.minPadding` and `xAxis.maxPadding` to `0` as well.

JS:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'area',
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginRight: 0
  },

  xAxis: {
    visible: false,
    minPadding: 0,
    maxPadding: 0
  },

  yAxis: {
    visible: false
  },

  series: [{
    data: [4, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3]
  }]

});
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9w26fyu1/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minPadding
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.maxPadding